# SASS division in @include not compiling

Tags: sass, mixins

I want to divide the grid-height with 2. But, it is not compiled to the expected value. Instead, it is compiled like this.

This my scss code. I tried different combinations. None of them worked. Kindly point where the mistake is.

```
@mixin phone-size($width, $height) {
  @media screen and (min-height: $height) and (min-width: $width) {
    @content;
  }
}

@include phone-size(360, 480) {

  $img-height: 90px;
  $grid-height: #{$img-height * 3 + 6px};

  .text-wrapper {
    $two: 2px;

    bottom: $grid-height / 2;
    bottom: #{$grid-height / 2};
    bottom: $grid-height / 2px;
    bottom: #{$grid-height / (2)};
    bottom: $grid-height / $two;
    bottom: $grid-height / (2);
    bottom: ($grid-height / $two);
  }
}
```

The compiled css code.

```
@media screen and (min-height: 480) and (min-width: 360) {
  .text-wrapper {
    bottom: 276px/2;
    bottom: 276px/2;
    bottom: 276px/2px;
    bottom: 276px/2;
    bottom: 276px/2px;
    bottom: 276px/2;
    bottom: 276px/2px;
  }
}
```

I am using http://www.sassmeister.com/ for testing. 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

## {} is not necessary

http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#interpolation_

$grid-height: ($img-height * 3) + 6px;

bottom: $grid-height / 2; //>> bottom: 138px;